# How to customize operation params appearance in SOAP message?

Tags: wcf, soap

I have WCF service with operation `string GetData(DataRequest request)`.
When I'm calling it, request SOAP message is something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  ...
  <s:Body ...>
    <GetData xmlns="http://...">
      <request>
        ...
      </request>
    </GetData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I want to customize `request` XML element without renaming my operation's parameter (using some attribute or so on). Is there a way to do this? And get something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  ...
  <s:Body ...>
    <GetData xmlns="http://...">
      <myRequest>
        ...
      </myRequest>
    </GetData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Attribute `MessageParameter` can be used to achieve desired look:

`string GetData([MessageParameter(Name = "myRequest")] DataRequest request)`